# How to use AWS CopyObjectRequest when Source and Destination buckets have different AccessKey & Secret

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core

I have 2 different buckets with different AccessKeys and Secrets. So I created 2 different s3Client objects to interact with them.

I am trying to figure out how to use [CopyObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingNetSDK.html) to copy a file from Bucket A (source) to Bucket B (destination).

SourceBucket property of this CopyObjectRequest class is a simple string name of the bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to use a `CopyObjectRequest` unless you have a single set of credentials with the appropriate permissions to perform all the needed actions on both buckets.

This uses the service API's [`PUT Object Copy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) operation, which is a request sent to the target bucket, directing the target bucket to fetch the object directly from the source bucket *with the identity of the user that signed the request against the target bucket* and store a copy... avoiding the need to download and re-upload the object.  There is no support for a second set of credentials in this model because no direct interaction with the source bucket occurs -- the interaction with the source bucket occurs inside of S3, as does the data transfer, even across regions.

The only option for using two sets of credentials is download, then upload.

Comment: That is what I thought but wanted to confirm if my assumption was correct. Tx for that.